Validation not working in HTML file when assigned to a variable in the ts file (Angular)
I am starting with Angular basics, I have the below code to assign a class to a button based on the button name which is received as a prop like below in component.ts file,
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import type { ButtonProps } from './reuseable-button-types';

@Component({
  selector: 'button',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrl: './button.component.css',
})
export class ReusableButtonComponent {
  @Input({ required: true })
  buttonProps: ButtonProps = {
    buttonName: '',
    handleClick: () => {
      //
    },
  };
}

button.component.html =>
<button
  (click)="buttonProps.handleClick()"
  class="reusable-button {{ buttonProps.buttonClass }}"
  type="button"
  [class.yes-button]="buttonProps.buttonName === 'Yes'"
  [class.no-button]="buttonProps.buttonName === 'No'"
>
  {{ buttonProps.buttonName }}
</button>

The above code works fine with 'yes-button' and 'no-button' class names getting assigned to the button when the button name is 'Yes' or 'no'. But when I assign the value to a variable inside the component.ts file classes are not getting assigned as expected. See the below code.
button.component.ts =>
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import type { ButtonProps } from './reuseable-button-types';

@Component({
  selector: 'button',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrl: './button.component.css',
})
export class ReusableButtonComponent {
  @Input({ required: true })
  buttonProps: ButtonProps = {
    buttonName: '',
    handleClick: () => {
      //
    },
  };

  isYesButton = this.buttonProps.buttonName === 'Yes';
  isNoButton = this.buttonProps.buttonName === 'No';
}

button.component.html =>
<button
  (click)="buttonProps.handleClick()"
  class="reusable-button {{ buttonProps.buttonClass }}"
  type="button"
  [class.yes-button]="isYesButton"
  [class.no-button]="isNoButton"
>
  {{ buttonProps.buttonName }}
</button>


Can you send the whole file of the component? Because need to understand in which lifecycle hook you are using it. And also what kind of changeDetection strategy you component is?

Ok, I got it. Where exactly you are doing this?
isYesButton = this.buttonProps.buttonName === 'Yes';
Anyway, it should work.
But this is very strange (click)="buttonProps.handleClick()()"
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-73q2gg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts

Apologies. "buttonProps.handleClick()()" was wrongly added. "isYesButton" is simply a variable declared and assigned the value directly inside the component and not in any events. So I guess, assigning the value inside "ngOnInit" hook or using "getter" method will solve the issue.

When we write the class evaluation variables like below
isYesButton = this.buttonProps.buttonName === 'Yes';
isNoButton = this.buttonProps.buttonName === 'No';

They are only evaluated once during component load and not after that, but you want this to be more dynamic, so I suggest you can go for getter method, which will be evaluated each time the property is accessed and you will get the dynamic behavior you are expecting!
  get isYesButton() {
    return this.buttonProps.buttonName === 'Yes';
  }

  get isNoButton() {
    return this.buttonProps.buttonName === 'No';
  }

FULL CODE:
CHILD:
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `
  <button
    (click)="handleButtonClick()"
    class="reusable-button {{ buttonProps.buttonClass }}"
    type="button"
    [class.yes-button]="isYesButton"
    [class.no-button]="isNoButton"
  >
    {{ buttonProps.buttonName }}
  </button>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input({ required: true }) buttonProps: any = {
    buttonName: '',
    buttonClass: 'test',
    handleClick: () => {
      console.log('click');
    },
  };

  get isYesButton() {
    return this.buttonProps.buttonName === 'Yes';
  }

  get isNoButton() {
    return this.buttonProps.buttonName === 'No';
  }

  handleButtonClick() {}
}

MAIN
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { ChildComponent } from './app/child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  template: `
    <app-child [buttonProps]="buttonProps"/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  buttonProps = {
    buttonName: 'Yes',
    handleClick: () => {
      console.log('click');
    },
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.buttonProps.buttonName =
        this.buttonProps.buttonName === 'Yes' ? 'No' : 'Yes';
    }, 2000);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

You don't need to use getters. You are using changedetection = default, it means that this will work
[class.yes-button]="buttonProps.buttonName === 'Yes'"
[class.no-button]="buttonProps.buttonName === 'No'"

